# ffmpeg: How to handle color range conversions

Tags: ffmpeg

It's hard to find comprehensive documentation about color-range manipulation with ffmpeg. I'd like to know the recommended way to deal with the following cases:

1. Input is limited range, I want to output full range
2. Input is full range 4:2:2, I want to output in 4:2:0 full range
3. Input is wrongly flagged as full-range, I want to remux or re-encode  in limited range

For example to solve case #2, I just add the `-pix_fmt yuvj420p`option. It's working but I have a warning telling me the pixel format is deprecated. I try to find a solution with  `-pix_fmt yuv420p -color_range 2` but the output is washed out (limited range played as full)

Comment: For 3, which codec?

Comment: h264. Does it matter? are those informations part of the bistream and specific to each codecs?

Comment: Colorimetry can be stored within the bitstream as well as the container. Tools to modify bitstream data without re-encoding only exist for some codecs. H264 is one of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Input is limited range, I want to output full range*

Use the scale filter, `-vf scale=in_range=limited:out_range=full`

and set color range for the encoder and the container*, `-color_range 2`,

*if writing to MP4, also add `-movflags +write_colr`

---

*Input is full range 4:2:2, I want to output in 4:2:0 full range*

`-pix_fmt yuvj420p` and same measures as above for encoder + container.

---

*Input is wrongly flagged as full-range, I want to remux or re-encode in limited range*

Re-encode is same as 1 but set the correct in_range and out_range.

To remux H264, add `-bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0` (with `-c:v copy`).

To remux H265, add `-bsf:v hevc_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0` (with `-c:v copy`).

`-color_range 1` for limited range.

Comment: Thanks!
A few minor corrections and typo in your answer:

#1 ```-vf scale=in_range=limited:out_range=full```  _ instead of :

#2 Using yuv420p is also working when adding ```-color_range 2``` and ```-movflags +write_colr``` this way ffmpeg does not output a depreciation warning

#3 if input is limited range flagged as full range, then ```-bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0``` must be used.

Comment: *Using yuv420p is also working* --> not here. The color_range does affect encoder behaviour but not the actual range.

Comment: well, it worked with ```ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf scale=in_range=limited:out_range=full -color_range 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -movflags +write_colr -movflags +faststart out.mp4```

Does ```yuv420p``` impose a limited range? if so, what should be used if ````yuvj420p```` is deprecated?

Comment: See the signalstats filer to identify the high and low values.

Comment: well if I test the file encoded with yuv420p I get YMIN=0 and YMAX=255

Comment: Look at the high and low values.

Comment: However a ffprobe tells me it's yuvj420p. So ffmpeg corrected it without visible warning. It's confusing...

Comment: Yes, the color_range sets the stated range when encoding irrespective of the actual content.

Comment: @Gyan What does `-movflags write_colr` do and is it only needed when manipulating colour with the `scale` filter? It's not documented [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-57).

Comment: It writes stream color metadata in the container. Not really related to any filter.