# Processing GoPro videos with ffmpeg messes up colors

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am trying to use FFmpeg to transcode videos taken using GoPro Hero3+.

The problem is that any kind of processing (even dumping a single frame to a jpg file), makes the output colors look slightly bleak. I tried using different color formats, but the results are always the same.

FFmpeg video stream info is as follows. Original:

```
Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30232 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 180k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
```

Processed:

```
Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 11513 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
```

Example:

[image: Processed (left) vs original (right)]

Edit: The Simplest way to reproduce the problem is to dump one frame from a video:

```
ffmpeg -i GOPR2004.MP4 -ss 00:00:00.000 -vframes 1 output.png
```

Log:

```
ffmpeg version n4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181127
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GOPR2004.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : avc1
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: avc1isom
    creation_time   : 2019-09-15T20:28:24.000000Z
    firmware        : HD3.11.03.03
  Duration: 00:00:21.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30802 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30232 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 180k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-15T20:28:24.000000Z
      handler_name    :  GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 20:27:10:10
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-15T20:28:24.000000Z
      handler_name    :  GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 20:27:10:10
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-09-15T20:28:24.000000Z
      timecode        : 20:27:10:10
```

Comment: Does the solution here work for you? https://superuser.com/a/1405333/48078 — could be that the input is a different range.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @slhck I am going to try these options and report the results here.